# How to add attributes of element to angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to angular. I want to write a directive which has all the attributes that I added to it when using in html. For example:

This is my directive

```
'use strict';
app.directive('province', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            var markup = "<select></select>";
            var elem = angular.element(element);
            elem.replaceWith($compile(markup)(scope));
         }
    };

})
```

HTML:

```
<province class="form-control" data-target"elemntId"></province>
```

I want my `<select>` contain the class and other attributes that I added to directive in html.

output that I want: `<select class="form-control" data-target="elementId"></select>`

I used `angular.element(element).attr(attr);`, but it does not worked;

Any help is appreciated in advance.

**Edit**

I want all the attributes that exist in attrs of link function to be added to `markup`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you don't need to compile yourself. You can use template and replace instead.

```
app.directive('province', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<select></select>',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        }
    };
});
```

[See plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NfBUpcCxJVlx3t3yrYeW?p=preview)

Comment: I don't know this answer isn't accepted, yet, but THANK YOU! This is avery simple solution, and I didn't see it in any of the tutorials that I've been over, yet.

Answer (score 8):

I would iterate over directive's attr array and apply it to your template:

```
app.directive('province', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:true,
    template: "<select></select>",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var attr;
      for (attr in attrs.$attr) {
        if(attrs.hasOwnProperty(attr)){
          element.attr(attr, attrs[attr]);
        }
      }
     }
};
```

})

Directive Tag:

```
<province foo="bar" foo1="bar1"></province>
```

Compiled into:

```
<select foo="bar" foo1="bar1"></select>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3ZtnQ6)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `attrs` parameter of the linking function - this will get you the values of the attributes:

`attrs.class` and `attrs.dataTarget` are the ones you need.

You can take a look at the documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom) that elaborates further uses of the linking function